# system() function inside Shiny app does not work

Tags: r, shiny, system, shiny-server

Inside a Shiny application I want to execute a command with the system() function. This command should generate three files but it creates them empty.

The commands inside system() call an external software (vsearch).

If I execute it in R it works perfectly, the problem is inside Shiny. How can I solve it?

```
# LIBRARIES
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(pr2database)
library(Biostrings) # To save fasta files
library(base)
library(treeio) # tree manipulation
library(ggtree)
library(ggplot2)

treeplot <- function(tree, x){
  ggtree(tree) + 
    geom_tiplab(align=TRUE, size=4, color='#609ECF') + 
    hexpand(.3) +
    labs(title = x) +
    geom_text2(aes(subset=!isTip, label=node), # labels all the nodes in the tree
               size = 3.5,
               color = "#0063B1",
               hjust = 1.3, 
               vjust = 1.5) 
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      
      span(titlePanel("Shiny Tree"), style = "text-align: center"),
      
      radioButtons(inputId = "start",
                   label = "Select an option:", 
                   choices = c("Choose file .tre" = "file", 
                               "Search in PR2 database" = "PR2"),
                   selected = "Choose file .tre"), 
      p("_____________________________"),
      
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.start == 'file'",
        fileInput(inputId = "tre",
                  label = "Choose file:")
        ),
    
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.start == 'PR2'",
        selectInput(inputId = "tax",
                    label = "Choose taxonomic group:",
                    choices = c("Domain", "Kingdom", "Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus", "Species"),
                    selected = "Order"),
        textInput(inputId = "clade",
                  label = "Group name:",
                  value = "Suessiales"),
        # Help
        helpText("You can run the example to build a phylogenetic tree 
               for the order Suessiales, unicellular organisms of the 
               superclass Dinoflagellata."),
        fileInput(inputId = "seq",
                  label = "Choose file:"),
        actionButton("seqbut", "Do phylogenetic tree", style="color: #F9FBFC; background-color: #0063B1; border-color: #0063B1")
      ),
      
      p("_____________________________"),
      
      textInput(inputId = "nameb",
                   label = "Branch name:",
                   value = "AY525023"),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "root",
                    label = "Reroot",
                    style="color: #F9FBFC; background-color: #0063B1; border-color: #0063B1"),
      
      numericInput(inputId = "val_rot",
                   label = "Branch number:",
                   value = 87),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "rot",
                   label = "Rotate", 
                   style="color: #F9FBFC; background-color: #0063B1; border-color: #0063B1")),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("pr2"), 
      dataTableOutput("pipeline"),
      uiOutput("ListOfCharts")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  PutChartOnTop <- function(This, ChartList) {
    c(This, ChartList[ChartList != This])
  }
  
  ChartOrder <- reactiveVal(list("tree", "root", "rotate", "flip"))
  
  output$ListOfCharts <- renderUI({
    Order <- ChartOrder()[1:3]
    
    ui <- lapply(Order, plotOutput)
    class(ui) <- c("shiny.tag.list", "list")
    return(ui)
  })
 
  observeEvent(
    input$start,
    ChartOrder(PutChartOnTop("tree", ChartOrder())))
  
  observeEvent(
    input$val_root | input$root,
    ChartOrder(PutChartOnTop("root", ChartOrder())))
  
  observeEvent(
    input$val_rot | input$rot,
    {
      if (input$rot) {
        ChartOrder(PutChartOnTop("rotate", ChartOrder())) # add plot on top
      } else {
        ChartOrder(ChartOrder()[ChartOrder() != "rotate"]) # filter out plot 3
      }
    })
  
  fileee <- reactive({
    # Attach file
    if(input$start == "file"){
      treeR <- treeio::read.tree(input$tre$name)
      
      # Visualize tree
      viz <- treeplot(treeR, "Phylogenetic tree")
      return(viz)
    }
  })
  
  # Input SelectBox and TextInput
  mydf <- reactive({
    group <- switch(input$tax,
                    "Domain" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(domain == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Kingdom" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(kingdom == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Phylum" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(phylum == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Class" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(class == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Order" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(order == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Family" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(family == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Genus" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(genus == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence),
                    "Species" = pr2 %>% dplyr::filter(species == input$clade) %>% dplyr::select(genbank_accession, sequence_length, sequence))
    
    return(group)
  })
  
  # Function: convert p
  seq_clade <- function(x){
    seq_clade <- Biostrings::DNAStringSet(x$sequence)
    names(seq_clade) <- paste(x$genbank_accession, sep="|")
    Biostrings::writeXStringSet(seq_clade, "~/pr2_CLADE.fa", width = 80)
  }
  
  output$pr2 <- renderDataTable({
    seq_clade(mydf())
  })

  # PR2
  pl <- function(file){
    x <- c(paste("vsearch --sortbylength", file,"--output CLADE_sort.fa --minseqlength 500 -notrunclabels", sep=" "))
    system(x, intern = TRUE)
    system("vsearch --cluster_smallmem CLADE_sort.fa --id 0.97 --centroids CLADE.clustered.fa -uc CLADE.cluster", intern = TRUE)
  }
  
  output$pipeline <- renderDataTable({
    pl(input$seq$name)
  })

  output$tree <- renderPlot({
      fileee()
  })
  
  # ROOT
  root_out <- reactive({
    if(input$root){
      treeR <- treeio::read.tree(input$tre$name)
      t <- ape::root(treeR, input$nameb, resolve.root = TRUE)
      tree_root <- treeplot(t, "Enrooted phylogenetic tree")
      tree_root
    }
  })
  output$root <- renderPlot({
    root_out()
  })
  
  # ROTATE
  rotate_out <- reactive({
    if(input$rot){
      tree_rot <- ggtree::rotate(fileee(), input$val_rot) +
        geom_hilight(node = input$val_rot, fill = "#0466C8") +
        ggtitle("Rotated phylogenetic tree")
      tree_rot
    }
  })
  
  output$rotate <- renderPlot({
    rotate_out()
  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: One problem I see is that you are calling `renderDataTable` on something that isn't a data frame or a matrix. And that you don't load `DT`. Apart from that, the call to `system` should work. But note it returns a character vector. Depending on what you are trying to do, wrapping the result of `system` with `as.data.frame` **might** be enough.

Comment: Thanks Jean, you are right that the object is of class ```DNAbin```, but it still doesn't work. Actually the code is longer and file is not the output, I put it to see which command was failing.

Comment: Then 1/ post the right code, don't post code where you are adding errors, so that nobody can help you tell which is which. 2/ post the error log from Shiny. If the program file is too large, there are ways to post it elsewhere and give the link here - if it's not sensitive.